# Is there a way to know in Apex if the user's mobile number has been verified?

Tags: apex, userinfo

Or can i know if that number was entered at "Advanced User Details"(verified) or "Personal Information"(maybe not verified)?

I want to check them before using "Auth.VerificationMethod.SMS" to avoid the error "User/Org configuration error: Could not send code due to :User/Org/Community settings does not allow phone verification".

Comment: What do you mean by verified number here? is it related to the format of the number or if it exists in the service provider directory (Active number)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved this question by finding the sObject "TwoFactorMethodInfo" and the field "HasUserVerifiedMobileNumber".
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_twofactormethodsinfo.htm